# PRESTASHOP1.6 Display categories block on product.tpl page

Tags: php, prestashop

My category block appeared fine on the left column on category page.
But when I clicked on single product page, the category block is gone.

I tried many things the last 2 days, it still won't show up. I tried to transplant the module to `displayLeftColumnProduct` (I assumed this is the left column in product page) but it gave me error saying that:

This module cannot be transplanted to this hook.

Then I tried someone else tutorial to paste this code

```
!$this->registerHook('displayLeftColumnProduct') ||
```

then

```
  public function hookRightColumnProduct( $params )
   {
   global $smarty;
   return $this->display(__FILE__,'blockcategories.tpl');
   }

  public function hookLeftColumnProduct($params)
   {
   return $this->hookRightColumnProduct($params);
   }
```

inside `getTree()` function in blockcategories.php but it's not working still

Help!

Comment: Hey, could you tell prestashop version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so did u enable product.tpl left column? You could see menu on left column by default. Just do this:

Go preferences->themes->Advanced settings and turn on product page left column. (http://prntscr.com/6xico8)

And this is what I see on product page now: http://prntscr.com/6xicxh . If still nothing, try to reset your category module to default. This should help.